# Deploying Apollo GraphQL Server on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to deploy a sample Javascript based Apollo GraphQL Server on Azure, but its not working. Following approaches were tried

```
1) Create Azure Web App (Linux + Node Runtime) with ZipDeploy of tested app
2) Create Web App with Node Starter template and do ZipDeploy
3) Create Ubuntu VM and install Node+NPM followed by deploying app
```

In all above cases, I suspect the port issue, but I could not spot the right tweak. The sample NodeJS app with apollo server was created using following tutorial

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html

If someone has successfully deployed apollo graphql server, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Dockerize a Node app and deploy to your favorite host while exposing the correct port. Azure Container Service is probably not the best option since it's very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy this node.js web app just as you would any other node.js web application in to Azure App Service. So without knowing any more details, I would say #1.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should work just fine. As the OP alluded to, you will have issues if you don't set the port though. Azure exposes the port via `process.env.PORT` for you to set. Here's the Apollo example with the required tweak:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

// Azure will set `process.env.port` so use it (or 4000 for local dev)
server.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

When using `ApolloServer` from the core `apollo-server` package, the underlying implementation uses the node http package (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Any options we pass into the `ApolloServer.listen` method are then passed into `http.Server.listen` (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen).

Here is where the received options are passed through into the httpServer: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/a3282a2d7df0c20d9e10b058defae835120fa5b1/packages/apollo-server/src/index.ts#L152